# Scalable Solution to fetch Initial State from API for Functional Components

Tags: reactjs, redux

The documentation and examples I have found around loading initial state prescribe loading data in a lifecycle hook, for classes, or in a useEffect with an empty dependency array. I am having trouble finding a more scalable solution.

Is there a recommendation against checking for null or stale state values in the action and then asynchronously populating? This would leave children components to re-render when the state is updated with initial values, as a result of connect() or useSelector().

The goal being to prevent each component from managing the state and centralizing API call for a growing enterprise application.

Comment: You have to study react-query. Because react query provides: Fetch, cache, and update data in your React and React Native applications all without touching any "global state".

Comment: may this link help https://betterprogramming.pub/clean-api-call-with-react-hooks-3bd6438a375a.

Comment: What you're describing as your goal is just the general architecture of a react/redux app. There's many different ways to cache data client-side, and many different libraries to support that. You need to give us a concrete example of your code in its non-scalable version in order to help you.